# Compressing large image to small format

Tags: c#, image, binary, compression

I have images stored in DB as binary, to show them I want to compress them to smaller images (4000 x 3000) to (400 x 300), which basicly works however the images look awefull, can somebody point me to the right direction?

I am using now:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream myMemStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
        System.Drawing.Image fullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemStream);
        Type typeoff = fullsizeImage.GetType();
        double height = fullsizeImage.Height;
        double width = Convert.ToDouble(fullsizeImage.Width);
        double aspect = setWidth / width;
        setHeight = Convert.ToInt32(aspect * height);
        System.Drawing.Image newImage = fullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(Convert.ToInt32(setWidth), setHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        System.IO.MemoryStream myResult = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream imageMemStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageMemStream))
            {
                ImageFormat imageFormat = bitmap.RawFormat;
                if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
                {
                    newImage.Save(myResult, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif))
                {
                    newImage.Save(myResult, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                }
                if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp))
                {
                    newImage.Save(myResult, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                }
                if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png))
                {
                    newImage.Save(myResult, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                }
                if (bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon))
                {
                    newImage.Save(myResult, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon);
                }
            }
        }
        _bytes = myResult.ToArray();  //Returns a new byte array.
```

Have been looking to this but have no idea yet how to implenet ths with my binary in and output:

```
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(fullsizeImage, Convert.ToInt32(newWidth), setHeight);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(fullsizeImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, Convert.ToInt32(newWidth), setHeight));
            _bytes = gr.T.ToArray();
        }
```

Probebly I do something wrong but have no idea where to look to do this right, have not much experience in image compression.

Any help would be appriciated

UPDATE

trying to get out of the Image the mime type but not very lucky to get it, using this and cant find any other, code has a null return.

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image newImage)
    {

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        ImageFormat format = newImage.RawFormat;
        if (ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == format.Guid) != null)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == format.Guid);
            string mimeType = codec.MimeType;
        }
        newImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: `GetThumbnailImage` is not meant to priduce quality output. Use the `DrawImage` overload with __two__ rectanlges!

Comment: You have any example I can look to somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to create the reduced `Images`:

```
public static Image ShrinkImage(Image original, int scale)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(original.Width / scale, original.Height / scale,
                            original.PixelFormat);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        G.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0,0,original.Width, original.Height);
        Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0,0,bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        G.DrawImage(original, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        bmp.SetResolution( original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);
    }
    return (Image)bmp;
}
```

Note that it can only work with real `Bitmap Images`, not with `Icons`; but it makes little sense trying to reduce icons anyway!

Also note that you may or may not want to change the `Dpi` of the new Images. In the code I don't but **maybe** you want to scale it up or set it to a fixed value..

Don't forget to `Dispose` of your `Images`, when you're done with them!

Comment: I have Gif, JPEG, jpg no others as far I know, will try this out tomorrow )) thx for the samplem and will revert on this for sure.

Comment: After some fooling around with scale and other things got it working with nice quality, however what I still do dont get is how to Dispose the image as I convert them to binary back again they should be flushed automaticly right? Another thing is I seems not to be abe to get out the mime type so I am limited to output only one type, found some code to do this however it gives a non found result on the image (see post)

Comment: The `Bitmaps` will __not__ get flushed and collected by the `GC` unless you `Dispose` them. (They are `GDI` objects and like a few other classes it is your responsibilty to `Dispose` of them. Usually my code would do it (since it creates them) but it can't as it returns them to you. When you are done with them do call Dispose on them! - The right place is hard to tell from here; could be after the `imageToByteArray`..

Comment: Thanks you have really saved me for some headache, images looking awesome. Still with the subject on use the right mime types which I am not able to detect, you have any idea?

Comment: Yes. Here you go: `string mime = GetMimeType(Image.FromStream(ms)));` and this little function: `public static string GetMimeType(Image i)
      {
          foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders())
          {
              if (codec.FormatID == i.RawFormat.Guid)
              return codec.MimeType;
          }
          return "image/unknown";
      }` - Note that you __have__ to call it with `Image.FromStream` ! I found it [here](http://programcsharp.com/blog/post/get-the-mime-type-of-a-system.drawing-image)